# Is there any way in Visual Studio to prefix comment while commiting?

Tags: visual-studio, commit, changeset, comments

From the screenshot below

[image]

I want to prefix my comment to the changes including work item's id. So I expect to get this:

> TFS - 123: Want to prefix this comment with work item's id

Currently I need to enter work item's id in both places in Comment and Related Work Items sections which is borring. What I want is just pass them into one place (Related Work Items section) and when I click `Check In` Visual studio will automatically prefix my comment.

Would be nice to set some pattern how to prefix:
`TFS - {id}: {comment}` or something like that in Visual Studio settings.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to duplicate the ID into the comment when, as you've already observed, it's being stored in a *structured* and searchable manner as a Related Work Item?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, customer requirements